# AngularJS: Filtering array before directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter, angularjs-digest

I've got a directive which I want to use in different cases, but all of them will be providing a list (array) from which it will take the information.

The problem is that every array will be / can be filtered by multiple filters (and some of them are custom filters). For example:

```
<select-search data-list="Ctrl.players | playersByDate:Ctrl.event.datetime | orderBy: 'name'"></select-search>
```

Those arrays, as I said, can have one, multiple or zero filters applied, some of them custom-made and some of them not (like `orderBy`). The problem is that when I do this, I get a `$digest` cycle error with any filters (custom-made and Angular filters aswell).

First, I've read the reasons why, but I do not understand them, because **I'm using a one-way binding** on the list:

```
scope:{
    property: '@',
    ref: "=",
    list: "<",
    change: "&?"
}
```

Therefore, **it should only be triggering once** (when it's filtered the first time), because after this no other changes are made in any of the sides.

Regarding this, I would like to know **how can I filter the list/array at the moment of sending it to the directive** (so, not filtering and storing it via JS in another variable) without getting any `$digest` error.

### EDIT:

As requested, I've written the code in a snippet ([JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pqrasybh/)):

```js
(function(){
var app = angular.module("AppMd", []);

app.controller("Control", [function(){
 var vm = this;
  
  vm.players = [
   {name: 'Player 1'},
    {name: 'Player 2'},
    {name: 'Player 3'}
  ];
}]);

app.directive("selectSearch", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      list: "<"
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<ul><li data-ng-repeat="obj in list">{{obj.name}}</li></ul>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude){
      return false;
    }
  }
});
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="AppMd" ng-controller="Control as Ctrl">
<select-search data-list="Ctrl.players | orderBy: 'name'"></select-search>
</div>
```

As you can see, it works, but if you look at the console, you'll see the errors it triggers.

Thank you!

Comment: can you create a plunkar?

Comment: Done! I've added the code snippet. Thank you for your help!